# Best practices for organizing ZF2 service factory classes

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2, service factories are scattered across the library with the heaviest concentration being in `Zend\Mvc\Service`.  There are also service factories in `Zend\View\Helper\Service`, `Zend\Navigation\Service`, and a few other places.  I have been unable to find any official best practices concerning service factory organization.

I thought that perhaps the MVC-based services were interdependent, but that's not always the case (see `Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewJsonStrategyFactory`).  I also considered the idea that maybe the library-specific service factories had no outside dependencies, but that's not always the case (see `Zend\View\Helper\Service\IdentityFactory`).

Are there "official" best practices concerning the organization of ZF2 service factory classes?  How do you organize factory classes?

Comment: It simply depends on what the Services are used for. Services have use-case and therefore they belong into a specific folder. Wouldn't make must sense to have some FormService inside a global Service folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent any documentation, best practice is to work with the grain of the code.  As you observed, the grain of the code is to store in a `/Service` directory (and namespace according to PSR-0 rules with the class ending in `Factory`).  As @sam noted, which `/Service` directory depends upon the service's use case.

This is how we operate in our ZF2 applications.

ZF3 may declare a specific best practice... though I doubt it[/opinion].  Consider asking on #zftalk.dev on @freenode.net

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there is an official convention.

What we do in our office is stick factories inside the `<Module>\Factory` namespace. Or more generally in the `Factory` sub-namespace right inside the top level namespace (`FooModule\Factory`, `Vendor\FooModule\Factory`, etc.).

So, for the following classes:

- `App\Form\Delivery`
- `App\Form\Fieldset\Contact`
- `App\Listener\IdentityProvider`

We would have the factory classes:

- `App\Factory\Form\Delivery`
- `App\Factory\Form\Fieldset\Contact`
- `App\Factory\Listener\IdentityProvider`